# "for" translation into lists high order functions

Tags: scala

As far as I understand, `for` expressions are translated into Scala expressions which are build upon:

- map
- flatMap
- filterWith
- foreach

High order lists methods.

A common example is the one where:

```
for(b1 <= books; b2 <- books if b1 != b2;
    a1 <- b1.authors; a2 <- b2.authors if a1 == a2) yield a1;
```

Results in:

```
books flatMap (b1 => 
    books withFilter( b2 => b1 != b2) flatMap( b2 => 
        b1.authors flatMap ( a1 => 
            b2.authors withFilter ( a2 => a2 == a1 ) map ( a2 => a1 )
        )
    )
)
```

Where:

- `books` is a list of class `Book` objects (`List[Book]`)
- `Book` has a public attribute `authors` of type `List[String]`

My question is about this line:

```
b2.authors withFilter ( a2 => a2 == a1 ) map ( a2 => a1 )
```

Since the condition is `a2 == a1` that line is equivalent to:

```
b2.authors withFilter ( a2 => a2 == a1 ) map ( x => x )
```

Why the generated code isn't just?

```
b2.authors filter ( a2 => a2 == a1 )
```

Can it be explained by the fact that the example is the reproduction of code automatically generated by Scala's compiler?

Is `filter` out of the for "building bricks"?

Comment: If you replace `filter` by `withFilter` in your last statement I think that the two are exactly the same and the difference can be explained by the fact that you're looking at compiler generated code. However, using `filter` changes things by constructing a new collection instead of an iterator whose contents are lazily iterated over.

Comment: @mrmcgreg Yes, `withFilter` generates its contents lazily but if you apply a map, parametrized with identity, over it you end with the same effect than `filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation of `for`/`yield` syntax into method calls is very simple and mechanical, almost at the level of string manipulation. `withFilter` is necessary in some places for its laziness, therefore it's used everywhere for simplicity. I don't understand the phrasing of your final question, but `for`/`yield` expressions are AIUI never translated into calls to `filter` except in a deprecated way for objects that don't yet have a `withFilter` method.

Comment: What I wanted to ask at the end of my question is whether the last `map` was there just to obtain the same behaviour as `filter` would have provided. And, if that were the case, I wanted to know why not just use `filter`.